# Angular JS binding scope data within ng-repeat to form

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a collection of items in $scope.data with fields "id","name" & "age", that are being displayed in the view using ng-repeat directive. 
For each set of items, there is a corresponding "edit button".

I want to be able to access values for the particular set of items for which edit button was pressed.

Html:

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="i in data">
        Name: {{i.name}}
        Age: {{i.age}}

        <form ng-submit="submit()">
            <input type="text" ng-model="i.id"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Edit" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
function Ctrl($scope) 
{
  $scope.data = [
    {id:1,name:"Alex",age:22},
    {id:2,name:"Sam", age:28}
    ];

    $scope.submit = function() {
        //access id of user for which edit was clicked
    };
}
```

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<form ng-submit="submit(i.id)">
```

JavaScript:

```
$scope.submit = function(userId) {
  // you have userId
};
```

Comment: Yep, or submit(i) if you want to pass the whole item (not just the id).

Comment: I'm very confused by this answer, what is addBrandModelFilter? Why is it not `$scope.submit = function(useId) {};`?

Comment: @Thomas you're right. I've corrected this. The error came from the fact that I wrote it quickly and copied the source code from my project.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of a form, I would suggest you just use a button:

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="i in data">
        Name: {{i.name}}
        Age: {{i.age}}

        <input type="text" ng-model="i.id"/>
        <button ng-click="submit(i)">Edit</button>

    </div>
</div>
```

Just send `i` into the button click event (I suppose you could use form if you need validation, but your example doesn't seem to need it).

Your `submit` function then changes to:

```
$scope.submit = function(selectedItem) {

    // here you now have access to selected item    
};
```

Comment: This solution worked for me while the accepted solution did not.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to just use an `ng-click` within a button that calls your submit passing in `i`

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="i in data">
        Name: {{i.name}}
        Age: {{i.age}}

        <button ng-click="submit(i);">edit</button>

    </div>
</div>
```

and the function:

```
$scope.submit = function(i) {
    console.log(i);
    //access id of user for which edit was clicked
};
```

Here's a fiddle of that working:  http://jsfiddle.net/pRAcP/