# Multipal Forms in Ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

there is forms inside ng-repeat. When i submit any form then last form is submitted every time that's wrong.
only selected form need to submit.
My code is

```html
<ul rn-carousel rn-carousel-indicator style="list-style: none">
   <li ng-repeat="story in stories">
    <form ng-submit="commentsSubmit($index)" method="post">
       <input type="hidden" ng-init="comment.itemID = story.news_id" ng-model="comment.itemID">
       <input type="hidden" ng-init="comment.owner_id = 1" ng-model="comment.owner_id">
       <input type="hidden" ng-init="comment.type = 'L'" ng-model="comment.type">
       <input type="hidden" ng-init="comment.from = 'app'" ng-model="comment.from">
       <input type="hidden" ng-init="comment.user_id = user_id" ng-model="comment.user_id">
      <input type="hidden" ng-init="comment.redirect = 'story'" ng-model="comment.redirect">
     <textarea ng-model="comment.content" class="textarea" rows="3" placeholder="Your Comment">{{ content }}</textarea>
     <button class="button--cta">Submit</button>
     </form>
   <li>
 </ul>
```

How i achieve this?

Comment: try `<button class="button--cta" type="submit">Submit</button>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already a similar question discussed about this,
FYI [form submission on ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19883222/angular-js-binding-scope-data-within-ng-repeat-to-form)

Pass the **object instead of id**, in your controller,

$scope.commentsSubmit = function(**story**)

Do submit like this, `<form ng-submit="submit(story)">`

```
$scope.commentsSubmit = function(story){ 
var comments = story;
    $http({ data: $.param($scope.comment) 
    }).success(function(data) { 
        MyCache.put('comments-'+$scope.comment.itemID, data.reviews); 
    }) 
};
```

Comment: i used this. In controller i try to get the data by this way `$scope.comment  =   {};
 $scope.commentsSubmit     =   function(index){
alert($.param($scope.comment)); return false;});` but return same as before, last form data

Comment: Your code is unclear. Can you provide your controller code? What is it that you are asking?

Comment: here is complete function for form submission `$scope.comment  =   {};
        $scope.commentsSubmit     =   function(index){
            var comments = RouteData.url+'/reviews/submit_library_ri';
$http({ data: $.param($scope.comment) }).success(function(data) {
 MyCache.put('comments-'+$scope.comment.itemID, data.reviews); })
 };`

Comment: i am success but change some code to do that. i use comment in form submit as `<form ng-submit="commentsSubmit(comment)" method="post">` and in controller function as `$scope.commentsSubmit     =   function(story){` and get data as `$.param(story)` then they return data that i aspect.